# How to split one long string of words into separate words in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

Im working on this problem that has a string of words with no spaces. I have to achieve is to add a space to this input between the words. Here is the code I have:

```
func getOrder(_ input: String) -> String {

let menu = ["Pizza", "Milkshake", "Fries", "Onionrings", "Burger", "Coke", "Sandwich", "Chicken"]

    
return ""
}

getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza")
```

Comment: Can you have "garage", like "he" inside "pizza" in the initial string for instance? Else, quickly done it could be: `var toReturn = input; menu.forEach { toReturn = toReturn.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: " \($0) ", options: .caseInsensitive) }; return toReturn` (it will replace the values with the one in menu (meaning with starting uppercase, etc.) Is that okay?

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, loop over the menu array and replace each found occurrence of a menu item with the item and a space

```
func getOrder(_ input: String) -> String {
    
    let menu = ["Pizza", "Milkshake", "Fries", "Onionrings", "Burger", "Coke", "Sandwich", "Chicken"]
    
    var result = input
    menu.forEach { word in
        result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: word.lowercased(), with: "\(word) ")
    }
    
    return result.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
}
```

Comment: I was using `components` but that would delete the word I was trying to separate.